# Cyclic adaptive spline in mgcv

Tags: r, spline, gam, mgcv

I want to fit a GAM to data with a cyclic predictor and most of the wiggliness is in a specific part of the cycle. Is there any way to make a cyclic spline `(bs = 'cc' or 'cp')` adaptive? Or, equivalently, make an adaptive spline `(bs = 'ad')` cyclic?

Comment: One trick to make a non-cyclic smoother look cyclic is to add shifted copies of the data before and after the real data.  If you post something reproducible, we can demonstrate this on your sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; this is already allowed for in the adaptive spline basis in *mgcv*.

The default basis in the adaptive spline is a P spline. You can switch to a cyclic version of that type of spline or use a cyclic cubic spline.

To get this to work, you have to pass information to the `xt` argument of the smooth function, while leaving `bs = "ad"` for the adaptive basis.

For the cyclic P spline you would do

```r
y ~ s(x, bs = "ad", xt = list(bs = "cp"))
```

and for a cyclic cubic spline you would use

```r
y ~ s(x, bs = "ad", xt = list(bs = "cc"))
```

The `xt` argument is often used for this sort of thing where a basis has other options that can be configured. The `fs` basis is similar, where `xt` allows you to control the basis used for the random smooths.

The other argument to look at is `m`; where `k` specifies the basis dimension for the actual smooth, you can use `m` to set the basis for the adaptive part, with higher `m` indicating more potential variation in the penalty over the range of `x`, just as `k` allows for more wiggliness in the smooth over `x`.

These details are discussed in `?smooth.construct.ad.smooth.spec` (or `?adaptive.smooth` as a simpler shortcut to that page.)